# How Do I Parse Through a Curl Request and Save Specific Values as String Variables

Tags: php, json, curl, http-post

Here is the Code ->

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.piano.io/api/v3/publisher/user/access/list',
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'api_token=*************&offset=0&aid=Q1rxzl1hpu',
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I am trying to parse through the output and save the email value, the rid value, and the aid value. I have tried json_decode, json_encode, but can't seem to get any loops to pull the correct data when using those two php functions. Looking forward to seeing more experienced developer insight here.

Comment: If that's your real API token, you should edit the question and remove it.

Comment: The documentation says that the API returns JSON. So `json_decode()` should do what you want.

Comment: Hi @barmar It returns data in json encode but after I have that variable should I just start using a foreach loop to capture the data I need?